# Reading raw perf counter from kernel module

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-module, perf

My goal is to read the intel rapl counter ([perf_event_intel_rapl.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/perf_event_intel_rapl.c?v=3.14)) introduced in kernel 3.14 ([lwn-link](http://lwn.net/Articles/572875/)) from within another kernel module. Reading "general" counters is easy using `perf_event_create_kernel_counter`. I have found an excellent example for that: http://wadeatwork.com/?p=1SW_CPU_CLOCK

The perf manpage ([link](http://web.eece.maine.edu/~vweaver/projects/perf_events/perf_event_open.html)) says, for "non-generalized" events `PERF_TYPE_RAW` should be used as `perf_event_attr->type` together with an implementation specific config field.

My question is how I should configure the `perf_event_attr` struct in order to access the rapl counters. I haven't found any documentation on how to achieve this from a kernel module.

Answer (score 0):

The perf_event support for RAPL includes generalized events that are accessible as system wide, requiring root access (sudo).

You should try the command:

```
sudo perf list
```

and see if the event power/energy-cores/ is there, if not, either your CPU has no RAPL support or perf_event does not enable the RAPL features on your CPU. If your CPU support RAPL but it's not enabled in perf_event, you can enable it by [adding RAPL support for your CPU to perf_event as described in this link](http://blog.factsmind.org/2014/12/enable-new-cpu-model-in-perfevents-rapl.html).

Once your CPU is supported, you can use the perf tool to do profiling with the command:

```
sudo perf stat -e power/energy-cores
```

For further details, this is [a guide with steps to sample RAPL events using perf tool](http://blog.factsmind.org/2014/12/polling-running-average-power-limit.html) that describes the above with detail and provides some code.

Comment: http://blog.factsmind.org/2014/12/enable-new-cpu-model-in-perfevents-rapl.html is a dead link :/